# Best way to display current logged-on user in default.ctp?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, controller

I am in the process of customizing the `default.ctp` file and I am trying to display the currently logged on user's name on the top of the page.

In `app_controller.php`, I have the following:

```
function beforeFilter()
{
    $user = $this->Auth->user();

    if($user != null)
    {
        $this->Session->write('user_name',$user['User']['username']);
    }
}
```

And in `default.ctp`, I have:

```
$user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');

if(!empty($user))
{
    echo 'Hello, ' . $user['user_name'];
}
```

However, it seems like the value `$user_name` is not getting set anywhere.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

---

**Update:** I've modified it as described in the answer, but it still doesn't work. I get an error:

> Undefined index: user_name [APP/views/layouts/default.ctp, line 21]

Comment: just use the array key that you use, ie username. also you dont need any other code in the controller like you had

Comment: @dog: Thanks. I just realized that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can also use the SessionHelper directly in the view / layout

```
$user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
if(!empty($user)) {
    echo 'Hi ', $user['user_name'];
}
```

Comment: With CakePHP2,  `$user['username'];`.

Comment: The field will be what ever it is saved as in the database. The version of cake has nothing to do with it.

Comment: For CakePHP3, we will now be using `$this->request->session()->read('Auth.User');` as the SessionHelper is now deprecated

Answer (score 3):

Cakephp 2.x:

```php
<?php if (AuthComponent::user('id')): ?>
<p class="navbar-text pull-right">
Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link"><?= AuthComponent::user('name') ?></a>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
 if(count($user)) 
           echo $user['name'];
```

Comment: All you did was copy dogmatic69's answer code, fix a tiny, minor error that would have been obvious, and didn't even bother to explain the code at all. If you had any rep, I would down vote.